# How to specify android:listSelector="@null" programmatically?

Tags: android, gridview

For some reason, I didn't have extra space around gridview's column borders in emulator but found out that the extra pixels in my real device (Galaxy S). So I would like to try:

```
android:listSelector="@null"
```

programmatically.

I know its related method is `setSelector`. But what number or id should I give for `"@null"`? I tried `0` but it made app crash.

UPDATE: I resolved the problem by making my own selector.

Comment: If you want to unset the `listSelector` drawable, use `setSelector(null)` instead of `setSelector(0)`. But I'm not sure, that it will help you with margins/padding.

Comment: Oops... Really, it does not working, sorry. Did you tried to set different background colors for every GridView child element to find out, the part of which elements are that extra pixels?

Comment: That's strange. I've experimented a bit right now and with default list item selector, I've got a one-pixel space between rows, but not columns. Probably this is version-dependent behaviour. Anyway, when setting `listSelector` to `@null` or `@android:color/transparent`, the border has gone. So why don't you use an appropriate layout for the `GridView`? Even if you want to create it programmatically, you always can use `GridView.inflate()`. So you don't need to use `setSelector()` method that possibly has a bug in it.

Comment: Glad to hear. You could still use android.R.color.transparent as a selector to reduce application resources.

Comment: I think, you exaggerate :) And the best thanks - to help somebody else here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this:

```
listView.setSelector(new StateListDrawable());
```

Will disable the selector :)

Answer (score 11):

Use

```
listView.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent);
```